# Python Socket Reply Port

Tags: python, sockets

How can I choose what port the Client replies with? The Server is Listening 5800 and I want the Client to replay with the port 5801. Is this possible if not what will happen if that port is not open. This is for FRC and it only has a limited amount of ports open and currently it is random.

Client:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
import sys


TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5800
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
nodata = 0

while True:
    MESSAGE = raw_input("Please enter a color: ")
    if MESSAGE == "":
        MESSAGE = "0,255,0"

    if "," in MESSAGE:
        print "you entered", MESSAGE
        break
    else:
        print "Not a Color."

try:
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.send(MESSAGE)
    data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    s.close()
except Exception:
    print "No Connection or Wrong Ip Address"
    nodata = 1

if nodata == 1:
    print "No Data Sent. Server Should Default Green."
else:
    print "sent data:", data
```

Server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket
#from neopixel import *

# Create NeoPixel object with appropriate configuration.
#strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(LED_COUNT, LED_PIN, LED_FREQ_HZ, LED_DMA, LED_INVERT, LED_BRIGHTNESS, LED_CHANNEL,
#                          LED_STRIP)
# Intialize the library (must be called once before other functions).
#strip.begin()

# Server Variables
TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TCP_PORT = 5800
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

# Neopixel Variables
LED_COUNT = 12  # Number of LED pixels.
LED_PIN = 18  # GPIO pin connected to the pixels (must support PWM!).
LED_FREQ_HZ = 800000  # LED signal frequency in hertz (usually 800khz)
LED_DMA = 5  # DMA channel to use for generating signal (try 5)
LED_BRIGHTNESS = 255  # Set to 0 for darkest and 255 for brightest

#Color Variables
color = ""
Red = "0"
Green = "255"
Blue = "0"

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data: break
    color = data
    print "Color Received:", data
    conn.send(data)  # echo
conn.close()

print "Color: ", color

#Color Choosing
Red, Green, Blue = color.split(",")
print "Red: ", Red
print "Green: ", Green
print "Blue: ", Blue
#for i in range(0,LED_COUNT):
    #strip.setPixelColor(i, color(Red, Green, Blue))
#strip.show()
```

Comment: Bind the client socket :)

Comment: Thank you! For other people you put 

s.bind((TCP_IP, RESPOND_PORT))

The TCP_IP has to be a variable or it errors out.

Comment: You should be able to use "0.0.0.0" for TCP_IP.

Comment: Im now having the issue where it wont go across 2 devices. Ive always tested from my device to itself but I cant do it between 2 even if I am sure that  the ips are correct.